# What the difference between $$ and \[?

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Why should I prefer `$$` to `\[` ?

I have always used `&&` and never had, seemingly, any problem !

Comment: Did you mean `$$` instead of `&&`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefer `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$` as per [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).